# how to extract precipitation data from netcdf file in R?

Tags: r, netcdf

I am trying to extract precipitation data from a netcdf file downloaded from the cordex climate model. I applied the following codes:

```
library(ncdf4)    
v1 <- nc_open('pr_EUR-44_ICHEC-EC-EARTH_rcp45_r12i1p1_SMHI-RCA4_v1_day_20960101-21001231.nc')
data_v1<-ncvar_get(v1,attributes(v1$var)$names[3])
```

I got this data:

[image]

Here, my need is to get the data with row number 1826.

I uploaded the 20 mb size nc file here:

https://easyupload.io/ch55ic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The array consists of 1826 matrices, each with 106 rows and 103 columns.

```
data_v1[,,1826]
```

Should extract the matrix you're after. Please refer to [Grouping functions (tapply, by, aggregate) and the *apply family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3505701/grouping-functions-tapply-by-aggregate-and-the-apply-family/7141669#7141669), for a concise overview of some useful functions for handling arrays.